# Trying to do a Find/Replace Across Several Lines in Several Text Files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several blocks of text that look like this:

```
  steps:
  - class: pipe.steps.extract.Extract
    conf:
      unzip_patterns:
      - .*EstimatesDaily_RealEstate_Q.*_{FD_YYYYMMDD}.*
    id: extract
  - class: pipe.steps.validate.Validate
    conf:
      schema_def:
        fields:
```

I want to replace this block of text with this:

```
  global:
    global:
      schema_def:
        fields:
```

The catch here is that the text crosses several lines in each text file.  Maybe there is an easy workaround for this, not sure.  More troublesome, is that is don't always have '`- .*EstimatesDaily_RealEstate_Q.*_{FD_YYYYMMDD}.*`'.  Sometimes the text is '`- .*EstimatesDaily_RealEstate_Y.*_{FD_YYYYMMDD}.*`' or it could be '`- .*EstimatesDaily_RealEstate_EAP_Nav.*_{FD_YYYYMMDD}.*`'  One thng that is always the same in each block is that it starts with this '  `steps:`' and ends with this '        `fields:`'.

My sample code looks like this:

```
import glob
import re
path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\output\\*.yaml'
regex = re.compile("steps:.*fields:", re.DOTALL)
print(regex)
replace = """global:
global:
  schema_def:
    fields:"""
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    #print(str(fname))
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        text = re.sub(regex, replace, '')
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
        f.truncate()
```

Of course, my example isn't simple.

Comment: `with open(str(fname), "w") as f:` that kills the contents of the file so it doesn't work

Comment: I just made an update to that code.

Comment: given that you call f.read() opening in 'r+' is just wasted resources. better to open once in read and again in write if you are not really going to seek to read AND write.

Comment: This looks like a `yaml` file, is the entire file in the same format? If so maybe you just need to load the `yaml` properly and change the keys/values, it'll be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing a general replacement of things between strings, I'd say this calls for a regular expression [EDIT: Sorry, I see you've since replaced your string "replace" statements with regexp code]. So if your file is "myfile.txt", try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
>>> content = f.read()
>>> f.close()
>>> replacement = ' global:\n   global:\n     schema_def:\n       fields:'
>>> print re.sub(r"(\ssteps\:)(.*?)(\sfields\:)", replacement, content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

The output here should be the original contents of "myfile.txt" with all of the substitutions.

Instead of editing files directly, the usual convention in Python is to just copy what you need from a file, change it, and write everything back to a new file.  It's less error prone this way, and should be fine unless you're dealing with an astronomically huge amount of content.  So you could replace the last line I have here with something like this:

```
>>> newcontent = re.sub(r"(\ssteps\:)(.*?)(\sfields\:)", replacement, content, flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> f = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
>>> f.write(newcontent)
>>> f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the best answer here probably. Will make this simple. Your mileage will vary with my example regex. Make it as tight as you need to make sure you only replace what you need to and dont get false positives.

```
import re

#re.DOTALL means it matches across newlines!    
regex = re.compile("steps:.*?fields:", flags=re.DOTALL, count=1) 

replace = """global:
global:
  schema_def:
    fields:"""

def do_replace(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        in = f.read()
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(re.sub(regex, replace, in))

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(str(fname))
    do_replace(fname)
```

Comment: This will replace *everything* between the first `step` to the very last `field`.  Possibly truncating the entire file to just `"global:... fields"`

Comment: I just updated my original code with your code; I incorporated your ideas into mine.  When I run this all files are stripped of all text, so something is definitely off here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: The 'steps:.*fields:' won't work here because it gets the first and last occurrence of both those.  The thing is, I have many of those string patterns in my file, repeating over and over, so doing it that way strips out everything in between the first and last instance of those strings, but I need to preserve that stuff.

Comment: Oh, wait, this seems to work: "steps:.*?fields:"
However, when I use that, it still truncates everything in all the files.

Comment: @Idlehands I did say "Make it as tight as you need to make sure you only replace what you need to and don't get false positives." I dont know enough about the file syntax to really give a real answer, OP will have to do that.

Comment: @ryguy72 maybe you just want to replace the first instance? You can add a 'count=1' to the re.sub to make it only replace the first instance. See my edit.